# Print changes values even though every index and key is constant?

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, hashmap, nested-lists

```
void main() {
  var count = 1;
  var a = {};

  exec(selectedOption) {
    if (count == 0) {
      print("NOTHING");
    } else {
      print("ELSE");
      a[1] = {};
      a[1]['values'] = [
        {
          "options": {},
        }
      ];
      a[1]['values'][0]['options'] = selectedOption['options'];
      count = 0;
    }
    print(a[1]['values'][0]['options']['selected']);
  }

  var b = {};
  b['options'] = {};
  b['options']['selected'] = 0;
  exec(b);
  b['options']['selected'] = 1;
  exec(b);
  b['options']['selected'] = 2;
  exec(b);
}
```

**Output**

```
ELSE
0
NOTHING
1
NOTHING
2
```

Why does value of **a** keep changing? After first run, a should not change. Am I right or am I just not made for programming? I'm using flutter and dart 2.12. I tried using Javascript also, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Both Dart and JavaScript handle maps (objects) the same way: by reference and not by value.

So what happens when you execute this line for the first run?

```
a[1]['values'][0]['options'] = selectedOption['options'];
```

`a[1]['values'][0]['options']` will hold a **reference** to `b['options']`. And since you change `b['options']['selected']` it is normal that 0, 1 and 2 is printed.

If you want to copy the current value of `b` instead of the reference, you need to do it like:

```
a[1]['values'][0]['options'] = Map.from(selectedOption['options']);
```

This will create another map instance instead of holding the reference and will produce the result as you expect.

Note: it would be better to do `a['1']` instead of `a[1]` since this is key in a map and not an array element with index 1.